# cpanm self-upgrade choking due Windows style 8.3 format path to site/bin

Tags: perl, path, cpanm

```
PS> cpanm --self-upgrade
You are running cpanm from the path where your current perl won't install executables to.
Because of that, cpanm --self-upgrade won't upgrade the version of cpanm you're running.

  cpanm path   : C:\Programs\Strawberry\perl\site\bin\cpanm.bat
  Install path : C:\Programs\STRAWB~1\perl\site\bin

It means you either installed cpanm globally with system perl, or use distro packages such
as rpm or apt-get, and you have to use them again to upgrade cpanm.
```

How do I either (a) make cpanm understand that these are the same paths, or (b) change the configured executable-installation path of Perl?

Comment: Just use cpan to reinstall `App::cpanminus`

Comment: Thanks, I just did a `cpanm App::cpanminus` and it appears to have worked. And to prevent potential other problems similar to this, I moved Perl to under `C:\Programs\berry\ ` (just to keep it under 8 letters), and edited `lib/CPAN/Config.pm`, `lib/Config_heavy.pl`, `lib/Config.pm` to replace `STRAWB~1` with `berry` in every path.

Comment: That's odd. `cpanm --self-upgrade` is supposed to be exactly equivalent to `cpanm App::cpanminus`, which is why I suggested using `cpan` instead. I don't know how you came to have this problem. I have had Strawberry Perl installed to `C:\Strawberry` for around ten years and have never come across any short file names, which are relevant only to 16-bit systems

Comment: You should write your own solution and accept it

Comment: @Borodin, I think his SP was installed to `C:\Programs\STRAWB~1` from the beginning.

Comment: @Borodin Seems it is doing a `check_upgrade` before installation only if you do a self-upgrade (`sub self_upgrade` in https://metacpan.org/source/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7039/lib/App/cpanminus/fatscript.pm ). With `cpanm App::cpanminus`, it treats it like any other package and doesn't do the check.

Comment: @ikegami: So where has `C:\Programs\Strawberry\perl\site\bin\cpanm.bat` come from if it's an alias?

Comment: @sundar: `cpanm Module` always does a `check_upgrade` first if that module is already installed

Comment: @Borodin, It comes from his PATH, not from `lib/Config_heavy.pl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `cpanm --self-upgrade`, simply doing it as `cpanm App::cpanminus` did the trick. (There was an error that `cpanm.bat.AAA` could not be renamed into `cpanm.bat`, and that it would be renamed at next boot, but I just renamed it manually.)

---

And to prevent potential other problems similar to this, I moved Perl to under `C:\Programs\berry\` (just to keep it under 8 letters), and edited `lib/CPAN/Config.pm`, `lib/Config_heavy.pl`, `lib/Config.pm` to replace `STRAWB~1` with `berry` in every path.
(The last two files here are as suggested by an answer in http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=680994 , and the first one is from `cpan`'s output during `o conf`. )

This path change unfortunately doesn't help with making cpanm's `--self-upgrade` work though, as it prints the same error message as in the question, with these shown as the differing paths now:

```
cpanm path   : C:\Programs\berry\perl\site\bin\cpanm.bat
Install path : C:\Programs\berry\perl\site\bin
```

Huh? Aren't they the same paths? Well, line 634 of https://metacpan.org/source/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7039/lib/App/cpanminus/fatscript.pm seems to be where this check is happening, and that line is assuming the `$install_base` won't contain special characters - but the backslashes in Windows paths are seen as special characters by Perl. So, Perl sees weird characters in the Install path that are different from the cpanm path, and declares it a non-match.
Changing the regex match there to `/\Q$install_base\E/` would fix this, but an immediate solution as an end user is the `cpanm App::cpanminus` one at the top.